# Finding combinations of each element

Tags: r, combinations

I have a list of elements {1,2,3,4,5} and i want to find all the combinations of each element, i.e, {1,2,3,4,5,12,13,14,15,23,24,25,34,35 and so on} in R
Is there any inbuilt function for this?

Comment: The function you are looking for
 is `combn()`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
g1 <- expand.grid(0:5,1:5) #create a data.frame with all combinations
v <- as.numeric(paste0(g1[,1], g1[,2])) #convert combinations into numbers
v <- sort(v[(v%%11)!=0]) #sort and remove duplicate figures, like 44 or 55
v
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5 12 13 14 15 21 23 24 25 31 32 34 35 41 42 43 45 51 52 53 54
```

The same code could be written in a slightly more compact way:

```
v <- sort(as.numeric(apply(expand.grid(0:5,1:5), 1, paste, collapse="")))
v <- v[!!v%%11]
```

If performance matters, this shorter version would probably be slower, since it uses a loop with `apply()` while the first version is fully vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
unlist(lapply(1:2, function(m) apply(combn(1:5, m), 2, function(x) as.numeric(paste0(as.character(x), collapse="")))))
[1]  1  2  3  4  5 12 13 14 15 23 24 25 34 35 45
```

`1:2` is the range of number of elements to choose (also `m` in `?combn`), and `1:5` the vector source of combination (`x` in `combn`).

Here is a function that does it:

```
range_combn <- function(x, m){
  unlist(lapply(m, function(m) apply(combn(x, m), 2, 
         function(x) as.numeric(paste0(as.character(x), collapse="")))))
}
```

eg:

```
range_combn(1:5, 1:3)
[1]   1   2   3   4   5  12  13  14  15  23  24  25  34  35  45 123 124 125 134 135 145 234 235 245 345

range_combn(1:5, 1:2)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5 12 13 14 15 23 24 25 34 35 45
```